# C# Nunit tests from VS 2013 (Nunit v2.x), won't show in Test Explorer in VS 2017 (Nunit 3.x)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit-3.0

Good Morning

Note: I am new to VS and C# coding. Learning and have the following issue.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:** 
C# Nunit tests from VS 2013 (Nunit v2.x), won't show in Test Explorer in VS 2017 (Nunit 3.x)

**BACKGROUND:**
Recently identified good scripts for our application written with VS 2013 with C# based on NUnit 2.x.
I have copied them into my machine with VS 2017 and Nunit v.3.10.1 and Nunit3TestAdapter v.3.10.0.

Note: The Tests are running fine in another machine with VS 2013 and Nunit v2.x

**Machine and VS config:**
 - Windows 10 pro 64 bit OS with 64 bit processor
 - VS 2017: Default Processor Architecure is set to X64
 - At present, "Active Solution Platform" is set to X86 for build settings for my test project (Build > Configuration Manager).
 - VS Nuget Package for Nunit: v.3.10.1
 - VS Nuget Package for Nunit3TestAdapter: v.3.10.0

**What i have done or tried:**
 - The test project cs file contains [TestFixture] and [Test] in the correct places
 - I have tried cleaning / rebuilding the solution multiple times
 - I have tried restarting Visual Studio multiple times
 - I researched many articles here and in other venues
 - Can't get a straight answer yet if it is possible, or impossible or what is the solution.

Thank you very much!
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Install NUnit3TestAdapter Visual Studio plugin.

In Visual studio, go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates. At the dialog, choose Online from navigation pane, and in the search bar type `NUnit`, pick the NUnit 3 Test Adapter plugin and install it. Once done, you will be required to restart Visual Studio and rebuild your test project.

Comment: Thank you Fahad. I already done this and currently have latest version of NUnit and Nunit Adapter. However the issue is stiil there..

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my friend Fahad, the issue seems to be resolved with the following steps:

- Unistalled Nunit3TestAdapter v.3.10.0 and Nunit3 v.3.10.0
- Manually removed all the "nunit.*" references
- Installed the following via NuGet:

  - Nunit3 v.3.10.1 and Nunit3TestAdapter v.3.10.0
  - Nunit.ConsoleRunner v.3.8.0
- Updated VS 2017 to the version 15.7.3

So at this point I see all the Tests in the Test Explorer. I have another issue with them not running due to this (but possible it is a different issue):

[Warnings for not able to run Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4qRq.png)